# JS game development libs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, ember.js, meteor

I have a realtime tile set / map strategy style game that I'm building with JavaScript on the client side, however I want to leverage an existing library or libraries that have perhaps thought through some issues more methodically than I'd be able to just starting off.

For example, I'm looking at Ember.js (playing with Backbone a little and even Meteor), however it seems that I'm missing some options as far as leveraging utilities that may already be in place.  What game js development libs have you used or seen that may be useful in this context?

Comment: Im not sure this question belongs here. However i'm developing a game myself but using javascript/jquery only.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you mean by not belonging here.  I've noted the libs that I'm attempting to use on the outset and I'm hoping to find supportive libs that will help the process, meaning you can obviously integrate other standard js libs into the aforementioned framework based implementation.  Are there certain areas of jquery that you are finding useful in your efforts as far as map design and navigation go @EH_warch?

Comment: nope, my map is just actually a board which is represented by a X number of hexagons representing an hexagon it self. You could moving this question to `http://gamedev.stackexchange.com` instead.

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of the gamedev exchange.  Thanks for noting that.  I would like to see what some folks yield here as well though.  @transparent's list is an incredible list that I'd not before seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a [list of good javascript](https://gist.github.com/768272/) game engines that I thought you might enjoy. :)

Comment: THAT is a very nice find!  Thanks for sharing that!